# Trouble with $_GET, $_SESSION and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, http

I'm in need of some assistance when it comes to working with `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` and the `XMLHttpRequest`. I have constructed a minimum working example to illustrate the problem:

**index.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['current'] = 2;
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>          
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>      
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content"><?php include('table.php'); ?></div>      
        </body>
    </html>
```

**table.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['current']))
{
    $_SESSION['current'] = $_GET['current'];
}

$current = $_SESSION['current'];

echo '<h1>Table Value = '.$current.'<br>';

?>
```

**browse.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['current']))
{

    $_SESSION['current'] = $_GET['current'];
}

$current = $_SESSION['current'];

echo '<h1>Browse value = '.$current.'<br>';
print "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Click here\" onclick=\"myfunc($current)\"/>&nbsp;";

?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function myfunc(input) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET","table.php?current=" + (input+1),false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;      


    xmlhttp.open("GET","browse.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;       
}
```

I use the Firebug console to keep track of what's happening. First let me point out that I set the async parameter to false because my server requests are so small. When I click the button `myfunc(2)` is executed and it requests `./table.php?current=3` and `./browser.php` from the server.

My thought was that since I request `./table.php?current=3` first, the session variable `$_SESSION['current']` will be set to 3. But when browse.php is requested the session variable is not set! This is what happens after I click the button once:

[image: foo]

Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have to use `session_start()` in **EVERY** script where you're going to be doing session operations. Since your table/browse scripts don't have it, $_SESSION will simply be the default empty array, and no values assigned to the array will be preserved by php at script termination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `session_start();` at the beginning of **browser.php**. (As Marc B comments to your question).

If you are not sure which script was included in another script which has already started the session, you may use

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

at the beginning of every php script.

To your reasoning:

> I set the async parameter to false because my server requests are so small.

The problem is the network communication which may freeze your page for significant time (or forever in some cases), regardless the size of the response.